# Why do I need set the size in Vector Asset utility in Android Studio 3.5.2?

Tags: android-studio

I know that Android Studio 3.5.2 has added a utility named  Vector Asset.

I know a vector draw can be zoom at any times.

Why do I need set the Size in Vector Asset utility? You can see Image A.

**Image A**
[image]

Comment: Did you try answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it makes no sense. So you just need to change Radio button to the `SVG` format, and you would see that area is disabled. Check image below.

[image]